# If $\log_510=\log_7x(\log_nm)$ then the values of x,m and n are?

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation

I have the question that if $\log_510=\log_7x(\log_nm)$ then values of $x$,$m$ and $n$ are?

This question looks easy but i tried to get the expression down to the form
$$\log_ab=\log_ac\tag{1.}$$
and i failed.
My attempt:-

the expression can be rewritten as :
$$\frac{\log_710}{\log_75}=\log_7{\frac{\log_7m^x}{\log_7n}}$$
After this step i don't get any clue to move forward. 

Edit:-

The question has options one of which is the correct answer:-
(a) $10,7,5$

(b) $-1,2,3$

(c) $7,5,3$

(d) $7,5,8$

Help please....

Comment: you have one equation with three variables -- there are infinitely many solutions

Comment: This is hard to parse.  Do you mean $\log_7 \left(x\log_n m\right)$ or do you mean $\left(\log_7x\right)\times \left(\log_n m \right)$?

Comment: @kamil09875 let me edit the question as i have some options.......

Comment: @lulu I think he means the former one

Comment: @lulu i meant former one

Comment: if you have the given options then just try every one, there's no general solution so this is the only one way to go

Comment: @MayankDeora: The correct option suggests the latter.

Comment: Oh sorry you are correct.....I have solved it ,Parsing error....

Answer (score 1):

HINT.- I hope this answer can help your inquire. If you take the function $$f(X)=\log_7(X)-\log_5 (10)$$ you have a unique and determined point, $a$, such that $f(a)=0$; this point is approximately equal to $16.183108$ so your “true” equation is $\log_n(m^x)=a$
 really.

(Optionally you have $$f(X)=\log_7(X)-\frac{\log_7(10)}{\log_7(5)}=
\log_7(10)-\log_7(10^{\frac{1}{\log_7(5)}})
=\log_7\left(\frac{X}{10^{\frac{1}{\log_7(5)}}}\right)=0$$ so you have $a=10^{\frac{1}{\log_7(5)}}\approx 16.183108$).

You have then to solve the equation $$\log_n(m^x)=a$$ If, for example (arbitrarily) $n=9$, the equation $\log_9(m^x)=a$ has a unique positive value, $b$, for $m^x$ since $a\gt 1$, $\log_9(x)$ is injective and its range is $\mathbb R$ so you have the equation $$m^x=b$$ Take now (again arbitrarily) $m=21$ and you have a unique $x$ such that $21^x=b$.

What conclusion can you have?  See at Kamil 09875’s comment.